# If $a+b=8$ and $ab+c+d = 23$ and $ad+bc=28$ and $cd=12\;,$ Then $abcd$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $a+b=8$ and $ab+c+d = 23$ and $ad+bc=28$ and $cd=12\;,$ Then value of
>
> $(1)\;\; a+b+c+d=$
>
> $(2)\;\; ab+bc+cd+da = $
>
> $(3)\;\; abcd=$

**My attempt:** Let $x=a\;,b$ be the roots of $(x-a)(x-b)=0$ and $x=c\;,d$ be the roots

of $(x-c)(x-d)=0.$

So, $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)=\left[x^2-(a+b)x+ab\right]\cdot \left[x^2-(c+d)x+cd\right]=0.$

Thus, $$\left[x^2-8x+ab\right]\cdot \left[x^2-(c+d)x+12\right]=0.$$

Where do I go from here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are $(a,b,c,d)$ strictly integers ?

Comment: ^I don't think the problem gives that, but there are at least $4$ integer solutions: $(a,b,c,d) = (3,5,2,6), (4,4,3,4), (4,4,4,3), (5,3,6,2)$.

Comment: (a-c-1)(b-d-1)=23+12-28-8+1=0

Answer (score 1):

This problem actually checks your observational skills of algebraic products.

Now take this:

$(x^2+ax+c)(x^2+bx+d) $

$=x^4+(a+b)x^3+(ab+c+d)x^2+(ad+bc)x+cd $

$=x^4+8x^3+23x^2+28x+12=f(x) $

$12$ is the product of roots so by putting $ x=−1 $ we find  $f(−1)=0 $

$⟹(x+1) $ is factor of $  f(x) $

Similarly  $(x+2) $ and $(x+3)$ are factors of $f(x) $

Hence  $f(x)=(x+1)×(x+2)×(x+2)×(x+3) $

This can be written in two ways:

$(x^2+3x+2)×(x^2+5x+6) $
$⟹a=3,b=5,c=2,d=6$

$(x^2+4x+3)×(x^2+4x+4) $
$⟹a=4,b=4,c=3,d=4 $

Hence $2$ sets of solutions are possible

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Pleas use MathJaX.